# Why Wikipedia doesn't appear as a referral in Google Analytics' Traffic sources?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, backlinks

One of my clients has a website and got not spammy backlinks in a Wikipedia article.

When I test it for SEO purposes with Google Analytics (from different IPs), apparently there is no referral information. On the Real-Time view my test visit is visible but with *There is no data for this view* in the referrals subview. And this visits appear as *(direct) / (none)* on the Traffic sources view.

Wikipedia is not hiding in any way its links origin, since it is shown in the server visits log. Is Google ignoring Wikipedia as a referral? Am I missing anything else?

**Update**: Now it works, several days after the link was active. Maybe something is detecting for how long the link was there so that it doesn't work just from the beginning, as a security measure? Many visits are actually not recorded.

Comment: Do you have access to the direct server logs? This will tell you if wikipedia sent a referer URL or not.

Comment: Also, did you access the site from Wikipedia's website or through something like a mobile app? Apps do not pass referer info and show up as direct traffic.

Comment: To add, are you logged into Wiki? is the URL HTTPS?

Comment: @joshuahedlund Yes, I just saw the latest visitors log in CPanel and wikipedia url is shown as a referrer. I'll edit my question, thanks. I access from a regular computer browser, not an app.

Comment: @bybe I tested it being logged and not (no https), and from other IPs in case it was detected somehow. Any way, I guess that my comment above changes the scenario. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have something to-do with no-follow links? (Wikipedia no-follows most external links). I doubt it, but I'm not sure how GA handles them

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak I don't think so. Other no-follow links work well.

Comment: Well, today it works. I don't understand... Editing again....

Comment: Glad you got your answer. I have had wikipedia show up as a referring site recently. I have not tested how any conditions to make the Wikipedia show up or not show up, so unfortunately cannot give a better answer. Perhaps the visit was too recent for it to show up in Google Analytics?

Comment: @Rober If you consider this question resolved, please try to add an answer below and accept it when you can - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For future reference. If you are using Universal Google Analytics then you can use Channel Grouping to add a specific referrer to a specific channel. You can also add things to channels based on medium and etc. Very useful.

This setting is under Admin -> Channel Setting

Answer (score 1):

As of 2015 wikipedia uses https for all connections

> To ensure that Wikipedia users can share in the world’s knowledge more securely, the Wikimedia Foundation is implementing HTTPS, to encrypt all traffic on Wikimedia sites.
> http://blog.wikimedia.org/2015/06/12/securing-wikimedia-sites-with-https/

Linking from secure connections to non-https sites will prevent the referrer from being transmitted.

> A user agent MUST NOT send a Referer header field in an unsecured HTTP request if the referring page was received with a secure protocol.  See Section 9.4 for additional security considerations.
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2